# What to do with Add-on questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

See [this question here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17714/where-can-i-find-information-on-the-spell-id-for-a-spell-used-by-the-wow-api) for an example. Does such a question belong on Gaming or does it fit in better over at Gaming Development? Is this in a similar vein to .ini editing, where the end user can make changes to the game without actually 'developing' anything, or am I totally off base?

(This is my first Meta question, please don't eat me alive if it doesn't belong or is poorly formatted)

Comment: OMFG THIS IS TERRIBLE __WHERE ARE THE FREEHANDED CIRCLES__

Comment: Just kiddin', just kiddin', no worries, and good question :)

Comment: I get to commend you for actually using the [allowed-questions] tag. Great first step into Meta, I says.

Comment: A note for the unfamiliar: WoW add-ons occupy a somewhat different space from, for instance Half-Life mods. While the latter are essentially changes to *gameplay*, WoW mods are generally UI tweaks and customizations.

Comment: Normally, I'd say that this particular question falls into your "development" category, but it turns out you can use it directly in the game to link items, so its one of those questions that bridges the gap....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm operating mostly under the function that an add-on can be treated like a mod. Which is to say that it is within our scope to a certain extent, what determines the full account is what kind of question it actually is. If I'm wrong, then it just chalks up another point to the fact that, like "mod", "add-on" is horrendously useless as a general term. So my thoughts are:

If the question about the add-on is more about development principles or quirks that are used in modifying them, then it would probably belong on Game Development, under the assumption that they are "mod development" type questions. (This is being questioned with some Game Dev folk, so don't get too hasty on migration flags)

If the question about the add-on is more on the vein of doing configuration settings to get it to work or within the predefined parameters, then it would be acceptable here. But all the same, like with mods, keep in mind that the developers of the add-on typically have better documentation than we will.